# Question on Expected Value, discrete case

Tags: probability

This is the question:

Suppose you start with one penny and repeatedly flip a fair coin. Each time you get heads, before the first time you get tails, you get two more pennies. Let X be the total number of pennies you have at the end. Compute E(X).

This is what I've gathered so far:

I think you need to first determine the probability mass function for X. And since X is dependent on the number of heads you get, I thought it would make sense to have another random variable. So,
Let Y be the R.V. that represents the # of heads before the first tail

I think then P(X = 1 | Y = 0) = (P(X = 1)/ P(Y = 0)) P(Y = 0 | X = 1)

I don't know if I'm even on the right track ... I don't know how to do the rest of this

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand the question. So when does the game end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea making a random variable $Y$ that counts the number of heads you get in a row before you get a tails. Finding a probability mass function for $Y$ just really requires really understanding what kinds of events $Y$ describes, and what a probability mass function is. $Y$ is the number of heads in a row you get before you get tails. A probability mass function $p_Y$ is a function where $p_Y(y)=P(Y=y)$. What kind of event does "$Y=y$" describe? It describes a string of exactly y heads in a row followed by exactly 1 tails. So it is easy to see that $P(Y=y)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}$. Incidentally, such a random variable is called a [Geometric random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). Now, simply observe that if $Y=y$ then $X=1+2y$.

Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: Yes I can, thank you so much!